# What's the difference between DetachedCriteria and ICriteria

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria, detachedcriteria

These classes have some similar methods but seem to work slightly different.

What's the difference between them and when should I use each of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Detached criteria can be built up without reference to an `ISession`. You can later take that criteria and apply it to an `ISession` to get an executable `ICriteria`.

Use `ICriteria` when you have a session.

Use `DetachedCriteria` when you're not sure against what session the query will be executed.

Note that `DetachedCriteria` does **not** implement `ICriteria` -- they are not interchangeable. You must always call `detachedCriteria.GetExecutableCriteria(session)` to get an `ICriteria` instance.

Comment: @kilonet Yes; seems bizarre. If you set a breakpoint on the second one and inspect the value of the local `category` variable, what is it?

Comment: yep, it was variable naming issue

Comment: DetachedCriteria is pretty cool if you work with generic data access layer